# I want to Redirect everyone accessing my WP Admin to my Homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wp-admin

I am trying to redirect all ip addresses to my Homepage except mine

I have tried to add this line of code to my .htaccess of my root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^121.122.111.114
RewriteRule .* https://www.google.com [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

It redirects me also to Google.com.
I am expecting all other iP address should redirect to my homepage. Only me with specific IP address should be able to access Wordpress Login (mysite.com/wp-admin)

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: The most probable explanation with what you have posted is that the IP address through which you are accessing your site is not what you expect. Your question/title mentions wp-admin, but your rule is targeting _everything_? Use `example.com`, not `google.com` when you need to exemplify your domain.

Comment: Why redirect to the homepage?  Why not show an "403 Forbidden" error?

Comment: You will have to change the matching pattern to only match your admin section's URL path (probably `/wg-admin`) if that configuration file is placed in the http host's root folder, as you wrote. And you should monitor your http server's access log file to find out what IP address you actually want to whitelist for the admin section.